# Why isn't the toggle button in my Vue template displaying collapsible content?

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Below is my Navbar template it's toggling but once you click the button the content is not visible. Once I click the toggle button there is no visibility of the content.

```
<div class="m-4">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg position-relative text-right">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-logo" href="#">
        <img src="../assets/logo.png" height="100" alt="navbar brand">
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar" @click="collapse = !collapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item mr-3">
            <router-link to="/about" class="nav-link">About </router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-3">
            <router-link to="/solutions" class="nav-link">Solutions</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-3">
            <router-link to="/careers" class="nav-link">Careers</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-3">
            <router-link to="/contact" class="nav-link">Contact</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-3">
            <router-link to="/pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mr-3">
            <router-link to="/developers" class="nav-link>Developers</router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Before resizing:

[image]

After resizing screen:

[image]

Comment: After resizing the toggle button, once you click its not displaying the collapse able content. I was thinking it could be related to bootstrap or in any case if there is a way you can handle it using a Vue method I will appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Don't tell us down here. Revise your question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: You can see from the syntax highlighting above that your markup has a problem. You're missing a closing quote mark on the RouterLink in your last list item. I'm not sure it's related, but it should be fixed.